# When I use while loop instead of if I get TLE error

Tags: java, binary-tree

This is simple code for in-order traversal of a binary tree. I just have a small doubt, if I use `while` instead of `if` in this, I get a TLE error. I want to know at what condition it will get stuck?

(I know we use `if` condition and with recursion should not use `while` here, but just to understand I want to know)

Can you please explain with a small example taking this small tree as where will get struck in this loop?

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

```java
   void inorder(Node root) {
       **while** (root != null) {
           inorder(root.left);
           count++;
           inorder(root.right);
       }
   }
```

Comment: `root` never changes, so if it is not null the loop will never terminate.

Comment: if we call inorder traversal(function ) with root.left won't it change ?If possible can you explain with that small tree i have provided?

Comment: This is basic Java: the reference `root` can only become null if null is assigned to it. You can see that there is no assignment to it, so its value can never change. The calls to inorder cannot affect the value of `root`.

Comment: to understand the problem: every time you call the function`recursion` (inorder) you will face the while loop and at some recursion levels the `root` will not be null so you will call the `recursion` again (your method `inorder`) and so on so you will not be able to terminate ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the tree is never null. So even if you iterate and traverse the entire tree and it returns back to the initial call of the `inorder` method, the root will never be null and the while loop will execute again and thus traverse the tree infinitely.

As an example, it starts with 1, then goes to 2, then goes to 3. The first iteration at the root is done. But since the root is never null, it will iterate again by going to 2 then 3 ... infinitely iterating the tree.